# Expected Angle of a Random 2D Vector

Tags: probability, statistics

I was playing around a bit until I noticed that the definition of sample correlation coefficient of two variables is literally the definition of the dot product of two realizations of the variable

$$ r\equiv \frac{\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y}}{|x||y|} = \cos\phi$$

Given a single observation $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,x_2) \in \Omega_{X,Y}$, note

$$\cos\phi = \frac{\mathbf{x}\cdot\hat{i}}{|x|}=\frac{x}{|x|}$$

In which case 
$$\mathbb{E}[\cos\phi] = \int\limits_{\mathbf{x}\in\Omega}\cos(\phi|\mathbf{x})\mathbb{P}(x_1,x_2)$$

The continuous correlation coefficient is:

$$\rho \equiv \frac{\mathbb{E}[XY]}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}$$

I'm wondering if the correlation coefficient can be interpreted as the expected angle of a random 2D vector?

If not, can you interpret the correlation coefficient of a 2D vector geometrically?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Geometric_interpretation